# Create a ID loop for a stored proceedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a list of about 500 `ModuleID's` that I'd like to run through the stored procedure below. Rather than copy paste each one individually I'm assuming there's a way I can create a loop and do it programmatically.

```
USE [mydb]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[DeleteModule]
        @ModuleId = 3363

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to do this - your script to generate list of queries, which you can copy/paste and execute, or to write a query, which will generate dynamic SQL and execute it.

First option is easier - just write a simple select statement like this:

```
select CONCAT('exec [dbo].[DeleteModule] ', ModuleId)
from [Table with module IDs]
where ModuleId is not null
```

When you execute the script above, it will give you a list of statements, which you can copy, paste in a query window and execute it. It is convenient for one-time or maintenance tasks.

The other option is to generate these queries and execute them dynamically. The easiest way to do it is using a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) loop through the data, generate the query and execute it with [exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @ParamsDefinition nvarchar(max), @CurrentModuleId int
set @sql = N'exec exec [dbo].[DeleteModule] @ModuleId'
set @ParamsDefinition  = N'@ModuleId int'
declare cModules cursor local fast_forward forward_only read_only for
    select ModuleId
    from [Table with module IDs]
    where ModuleId is not null
open cModules
fetch next from @cModules into @CurrentModuleId
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParamsDefinition, @ModuleId = @CurrentModuleId
    fetch next from @cModules into @CurrentModuleId
end
close cModules
deallocate cModules
```

The body of the loop (between `begin` and `end`) will be executed for each row returned by the cursor, i.e. for each ModuleId. It will execute the statement in `@sql` for each value stored in `@CurrentModuleId`.